# Can't restore database with (apparently) same version

Tags: sql-server, azure, restore

I'm trying to restore a SQL Server database instance in my local machine I've backed up from an Azure Cloud environment but I'm getting the following message:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The database was backed up on a server running version 15.00.2000. That version is incompatible with this server, which is running version 15.00.2000. Either restore the database on a server that supports the backup, or use a backup that is compatible with this server.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dhtd.png)

The version seems to be the exactly the same, so it doesn't make any sense to me. Am I missing something? Or you just can't restore a backup from an Azure Cloud at all?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the source backup from an Azure MI? In that case, this looks like a [duplicate question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/259696/backup-from-azure-sql-managed-instance-and-restore-on-an-on-prem-version).

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6004/restore-azure-sql-database-to-local-sql-server/

Comment: Thanks @MichaelGreen. That's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 6):

The two managed types of SQL Server in Azure (SQL Database and Managed Instance) are version 12.0.2000.8. Don't be fooled by the low version number, it is always higher than on-prem meaning you can never restore an "Azure SQL" backup to on-prem.
You cannot perform a backup from SQL Database, but you *can* do a copy only backup from Managed Instance. This would be my guess.

Perhaps the error message is incorrect, and *should* have said that backup is from 12.00.2000

If it is the 3:rd type of "SQL Server in Azure", a VM with SQL Server installed, then it is of any version you like. This should be restoreable.

So, find out what type of SQL you have in Azure, then take it from there.